# In C#, is it possible to open a URL in the background, without opening a browser?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

My code needs to supply some information to a server via a php script.

Basically I want to call `www.sitename.com/example.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3` but I don't want the browser to open, so `Process.Start(URL);` won't work.

Since I come to this site to learn and not to get answers, mostly, I will explain what I've done so far and the errors I have gotten. If you know a solution anyway, feel free to skip the next part.

I have looked around, and I saw a solution for using POST:

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding=new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData="var1=1&var2=2&var3=3";
byte[]  data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

// Prepare web request...
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/site.php");
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream newStream=myRequest.GetRequestStream();

// Send the data.
newStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
newStream.Close();
```

However, I require the use of `GET` not `POST`. At first I thought the solution might be to change `myRequest.Method = "POST";` to `GET`, but this didn't work because that's not how `GET` works, it pulls data from the URL.

So, then I attempted to change the previous code to:

```
HttpwebRequest myRequest= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/site.php" + postData);
Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Close()
```

Under the logic that it would call the URL, which would (hopefully) initiate the GET_ request on the php script, and then life would be dandy. This however resulted in the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.ProtocolViolationException' occurred in System.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.ProtocolViolationException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
```

Any help is appreciated, and thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
string postData="var1=1&var2=2&var3=3";
// Prepare web request...
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                    "http://yourserver/site.php?" + postData);
myRequest.Method = "GET";
var resp =(HttpWebResponse) myRequest.GetResponse();

var result = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Or maybe even simpler:

```
var data = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://yourserver/site.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3");
```

See the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class for more options

Comment: for your first solution, Visual Studio 2012 produces and error and highlights `Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();`

for the second solution, no error is produced, but the php page doesn't seem to register anything.

Comment: If you use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) you can see which calls are executed over the system proxy.

Comment: I have found the problem. To get onto `http://yourserver/site.php` I need authentication through a central authentication server. So, when I try to access the site, it redirects me to authentication first. 

Do you know of anyway to get past that, given that I have the correct username and password? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You mostly seem to have gone down the right route:

```
string postData="var1=1&var2=2&var3=3";

// Prepare web request...
HttpwebRequest myRequest= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "http://localhost/site.php?" + postData);

// Send the data.
myRequest.GetResponse();
```

Note that I've added the `?` at the end of `site.php`.

We don't have to fiddle around with the request stream since that's all about putting things in the body of a request - and as you've stated, a `GET` request has its data in the URL, not in its body.

Comment: although this is very common, and will work in like 99.9% of all possible cases, this is not how HTTP was meant to function ... RFC2616 Section 9.1.1 states "that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) class. Using it it's just 2 lines of code, just supply your URL and use methods like `DownloadString`.