# Call a automatic Download URL without opening the Browser

Tags: c#, file, download, windows-forms-designer

I have a small problem with downloading a file.
I have used windows Forms and need to download several files. They all are avaiable through a link that, when its opened automatically downloads the file.

I tried several things like WebCient or httpWebrequest but it all doesnt work.

Do you have any idea how i can launch this link without opening the browser every time and safe the file to a specific folder.

```
                    foreach (var doc in newDocs)
                {
                    using (var wb = new WebClient())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("link" <- to cehck the if its the correct file;
                        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("link") as HttpWebRequest;

                        wb.DownloadFile("link" <- 'link' cause its sensitive data.);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `I tried several things like WebCient or httpWebrequest but it all doesnt work.` Please provide [mcve] of your attempts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, is it possible to open a URL in the background, without opening a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109011/in-c-is-it-possible-to-open-a-url-in-the-background-without-opening-a-browser)

Comment: How does the code not work exactly?

Comment: i think the problem is that the link, links to a site that initiates a download of a specific file but the file isnt stored on that url. its like a reference.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use `HttpWebRequest` and look into the `AllowAutoRedirect` property.

Comment: so i use my request from above and set the property of autoredirect to true?

Comment: @Equalsk Doesnt work at all.. :S

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

```
 void Download()
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("url"), @"filepath");
        }
    }

    private  void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private  void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it needs pass credentials or not when you download the file.

Comment: the credentials are within the link but i tried to do your way. and afterwards theres no file inside the path :/

Comment: any exception throw?

Comment: could you try to change the link which actual store the file?

Comment: actualy i only have this link where i put the document id in and open it. i cant access the filestorage directly..